# i want to set default theme when the user sing in for the first time in app ,without "selected" a button or a checkbox

Tags: flutter

i wanted: i want to set default theme when the user sing in for the first time in app ,without "selected" a button or a checkbox

i use:  "animated_theme_switcher" package from pub.dev for switch my theme to default theme
i want to set it in mySplashScreen but,

i donot kwnow where should i put this:
ThemeSwitcher.of(context).changeTheme(
theme: myTheme);

```
my Code:


*import 'package:animated_theme_switcher/animated_theme_switcher.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:background_fetch/background_fetch.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
    
    import '../pages/home_page.dart';
    import '../pages/signin_screen.dart';
    import '../pages/stepup_page.dart';
    import '../flavors.dart';
    import '../style/style.dart';
    import '../helper/helper.dart';
    import '../models/localappconfig.dart';
    import '../sqliteProvider/userappconfig_provider.dart';
    import '../ui/loading.dart';
    import '../utils/gradientutil.dart';
    import '../utils/uidata.dart';
    import '../helper/dbhelper.dart';
    import '../sqliteProvider/localappconfig_provider.dart';
    import '../models/UserAppConfig.dart';
    
    class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    State createState() => new SplashScreenState();
    }
    
    class SplashScreenState extends State {
    ThemeData myTheme;
    
    @override
    void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkLogin();
    initPlatformState();
    Helper.notificationPermission();
    // _configureSelectNotificationSubject();
    }
    
    @override
    void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    setInitTheme();
    }
    // void _configureSelectNotificationSubject() {
    // final selectNotification = BehaviorSubject();
    
    // selectNotification.stream.listen((String payload) async {
    // await Navigator.push(
    // context,
    // MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WarePage()),
    // );
    // });
    // }
    
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ScreenUtil.init(context, width: 750, height: 1334, allowFontScaling: true);
    
    return ThemeSwitchingArea(
      child: Scaffold(
          body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: PAGE_BACKGROUND,
        ),
        child: new Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                  width: 400.w,
                  height: 400.h,
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      image: new DecorationImage(
                          image: new AssetImage(UIData.imageSorooshan),
                          fit: BoxFit.fill)),
                ),
                new Text(F.companyInfo.appCompanyName,
                    style: Style.styleTextBlack(TEXT_SIZE_50, FontWeight.w700))
              ],
            ),
            new Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
              child: new Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: LoadingSpinner(Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )),
    );
    }
    
    Future checkLogin() async {
    DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper();
    var count = await dbHelper.getCount('LocalAppConfig');
    if (count == null || (count != null && count == 0)) {
    //set Default LocalAppConfig
    LocalAppConfigProvider configProvider = new LocalAppConfigProvider();
    LocalAppConfig config =
    new LocalAppConfig(1, 0, 0.0, DateTime.now().toString());
    await configProvider.insert(config);
    //set Default UserAppConfig
    UserAppConfig appConfig = new UserAppConfig(
    sql_Apc_Id: 1,
    token: "",
    isOnlineDateTime: DateTime.now().toString(),
    logOut: 1,
    setUp: 0,
    // primarycolor: "4294924066",
    // accentcolor: "4294924066",
    // fontsize: 22.0
    );
    UserAppConfigProvider userAppConfigProvider = new UserAppConfigProvider();
    await userAppConfigProvider.insert(appConfig);
    Helper.navigationReplace(context, SignInScreen());
    } else if (count != null && count > 0) {
    var mapuser = await dbHelper.getItem('UserAppConfig');
    if (mapuser != null) {
    UserAppConfig appConfig = new UserAppConfig.fromMapDb(mapuser);
    if (appConfig != null && appConfig.logOut == 0) {
    if (appConfig.setUp == 0)
    Helper.navigationReplace(context, SetUpPage());
    else
    Helper.navigationReplace(context, HomePage());
    } else
    Helper.navigationReplace(context, SignInScreen());
    } else
    Helper.navigationReplace(context, SignInScreen());
    }
    }
    
    Future initPlatformState() async {
    // Configure BackgroundFetch.
    BackgroundFetch.configure(
    BackgroundFetchConfig(
    minimumFetchInterval: 30,
    stopOnTerminate: false,
    startOnBoot: true,
    enableHeadless: true,
    requiresBatteryNotLow: false,
    requiresCharging: false,
    requiresStorageNotLow: false,
    requiresDeviceIdle: false,
    requiredNetworkType: NetworkType.ANY),
    _onBackgroundFetch)
    .then((int status) async {
    print('[BackgroundFetch] configure success: $status');
    await Helper.backServiceReception();
    }).catchError((e) {
    print('[BackgroundFetch] configure ERROR: $e');
    });
    
    if (!mounted) return;
    }
    
    void _onBackgroundFetch(String taskId) async {
    await Helper.backServiceReception();
    // IMPORTANT: You must signal completion of your fetch task or the OS can punish your app
    // for taking too long in the background.
    BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId);
    }
    
    void setInitTheme() async {
    UserAppConfigProvider _userAppConfigProvider = UserAppConfigProvider();
    await _userAppConfigProvider.getUserAppConfig().then((_userAppConfig) {
    if (_userAppConfig != null && _userAppConfig.sql_Apc_Id > 0) {
    myTheme = ThemeData(
    // appBarTheme: ThemeData.light().appBarTheme.copyWith(color: Colors.deepOrange),
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    fontFamily: UIData.vazirFont,
    // primaryColor: Color(int.parse(_userAppConfig.primarycolor)),
    // accentColor: Color(int.parse(_userAppConfig.accentcolor)),
    primaryColor: Colors.deepOrange,
    accentColor: Colors.deepOrange,
    // primaryTextTheme:
    // TextTheme(bodyText1: TextStyle(fontSize: _userAppConfig.fontsize)),
    
          // canvasColor: kLightPrimaryColor,
          // backgroundColor: accentcolor,
          // iconTheme: ThemeData.light().iconTheme.copyWith(
          //       color: Color(0xFF373737),
          //     ),
          // textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.apply(
          //       fontFamily: UIData.vazirFont,
          //       bodyColor: Color(0xFF373737),
          //       displayColor: Color(0xFF373737),
          //     ),
        );
      }
    });
    ThemeSwitcher.of(context).changeTheme(
      theme: myTheme,
    );
    }
    }*
```

Comment: Before posting a new question, Please review [how to ask](StackOverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specifically, code must be pared down to be a **minimum reproducible example** of the issue in question. It is recommended to edit the code in this question accordingly, to be of maximum use to future visitors facing a similar issue. Finally, **grammar**, spelling capitalization, punctuation, proof reading **is important**.

Comment: ...As is good code formatting, consistent code indentation, and removing unnecessary comments and code irrelevant to the specific issue at hand.  Code, and variable names referenced within the text description of the issue should be surrounded by single backtics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my problem,we should put our theme before runApp(new MyApp());
like this:

```
void main() {
ThemeData myTheme;
UserAppConfigProvider _userAppConfigProvider = UserAppConfigProvider();
await _userAppConfigProvider.getUserAppConfig().then((_userAppConfig) {
if (_userAppConfig != null && _userAppConfig.sql_Apc_Id > 0) {
myTheme = ThemeData(
brightness: Brightness.light,
fontFamily: UIData.vazirFont,
primaryColor: Color(int.parse(_userAppConfig.primarycolor)),
accentColor: Color(int.parse(_userAppConfig.accentcolor)),
);
} else {
myTheme = ThemeData(
brightness: Brightness.light,
fontFamily: UIData.vazirFont,
primaryColor: Colors.purple,
accentColor: Colors.purple,
);
}
});

runApp(new MyApp(
  myTheme: myTheme,
));
});

                                                and use it here: 
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
final ThemeData myTheme;

MyApp({
Key key,
this.myTheme,
}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MultiProvider(
providers: [
ChangeNotifierProvider(
create: (_) {
return AppCustomers();
},
),
],
child: ThemeProvider(
initTheme: myTheme,
child: Builder(
builder: (context) {
return MaterialApp(
title: F.companyInfo.appCompanyName,
theme: ThemeProvider.of(context),
initialRoute: "/",
routes: {
"/": (context) => Helper.prepareScreen(SplashScreen()),
UIData.receptionPointRoute: (context) =>
Helper.prepareScreen(ReceptionPointPage()),
},
debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
);
},
),
),
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it in `initState()`, like this:

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  // ......
  setTheme();
}
```

Comment: SO discourages code only suggestions. Quality answers include an explanation as to how/why key parts of you suggesting solves the OP's Q. Most upvotes are gained by future visitors learning something from your solution that they can apply to their own coding issues. Consider editing to increase the value of your contribution.

Comment: it was a short answer so everyone will understand because u said u want to put it on mySplashScreen so told u put it on initState and sorry if I wanted to help

Comment: Learning how SO works: It's recommended to tell users why that is the correct location, or link to the documentation, so users can understand why. Answers are here not only for the single person who posted the question, but for the benefit of all coders who may have a similar question, who visit this page in the future looking for answers. *Most* upvotes come from future visitors who were able to solve *their* coding issues based on knowledge gained by reading these answers.  Code-only answers are usually low quality. High quality answers, where programmers gain *insight*, receive most upvotes